# Compose compiler issue with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

While using compose in the existing project Gradle says can not get the compose compiler while building the project

> Could not GET 'https://bintray.com/rameshbhupathi/maven/androidx/ui/ui-tooling/1.0.1/ui-tooling-1.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

```
buildscript {
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    minSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 30

    kotlinVersion = '1.5.31'
    compose_version = '1.0.1'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{url 'https://sdk.uxcam.com/android/'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://bintray.com/rameshbhupathi/maven' }
    maven{url 'https://sdk.uxcam.com/android/'}
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's sth wrong with your network, 403 means server got the message but refused your visit.